# What's the best way to implement texting into my webapp?

Tags: api, text

I'd like to allow users to text to a certian number in order to complete actions on their accounts. An example would be

```
update name with Captain
```

Basically what I'm asking is about is a service that can receive texts and has an API so that I can use them for my site... Thanks for any help!

Comment: Which country are you in? Different companies work with different carriers in different countries.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it, but [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/sms/) provides a web-service based API for a number of phone functions, including SMS.  [Pricing seems sane](http://www.twilio.com/pricing/) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible alternative is to use email addresses. All carriers have email addresses tied to phone numbers. so you can simply use those email addresses for free to send/receive SMS messages if that works for you. Any phone can also sent an SMS to an email address, as opposed to a phone number, and as far as I know this has worked since years and years ago with every phone I've ever owned (even non-smart phones). This functionality just seems to be something mobile carriers all decided to include in their messaging systems.

You can find the list of carriers/email address domains [here](http://www.emailtextmessages.com/)

Typically the email address is [10-digit number]@[providerdomain.com]